# VM305:5551 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm getting this error on browsers console, and js file are not loaded:

```
VM305:5551 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

But if I use  a private windows, there is no error and the webpage works.

Answer (score 6):

I deleted the launch.json file, it worked for me

Comment: Where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem twice in React.js. Both while using libraries for pdf to image preview. One was Mozilla's PDF.js library. The npm package is known as 'pdfjs-dist'. When I removed this package, the error was gone and the server ran perfectly normal.

These libraries might be using old cr.js or module technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I suddenly encountered this problem today while I never encountered it before. Deleting the `launch.json` didn't fixed the problem. I opened that file and saw that the `url` tag was followed by `"http://localhost:8080"` instead of my HTML file's path. So I replaced `"http://localhost:8080"` with the path of my HTML file, then it was working again.

Comment: launch.json from where???